# shortcut to transforming a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'd like to apply a log transformation to all columns of my dataframe in Julia:

```
my_df = DataFrame(A = [1,2], B=[3,4])
```

What is a concise way to do this?

Comment: `log_df = DataFrame(map(x->map(log,x),(my_df[x] for x in names(my_df))),names(my_df))`

Comment: foreach(x -> my_df[x] = log.(my_df[x]), names(my_df))

Comment: This `colwise(log, my_df)` does the log, but doesn't collect the DataFrame afterwards (which I am assuming you need?)

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Yes. I want a transformed DataFrame at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
log_df = DataFrame(;Dict(c=>log(my_df[c]) for c in names(my_df))...)
```

seems to be quite compact. But the other comments and answers are good as well. This does not do the transformation in-place. To do it in-place, use:

```
foreach(x -> my_df[x] = log(my_df[x]), names(my_df))
```

suggested by Bogumił (withtout the broadcast, see below).

Additionally, there is the issue of `log(c::DataArray)` broadcasting automatically, which makes `log.(c::DataArray)` return rubbish:

```
julia> log(my_df[:A])
2-element DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}:
 0.0     
 0.693147

julia> log.(my_df[:A])
0-dimensional DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,0}:
0.0
```

Comment: Interesting. Under Julia 0.6 rc1 `log.(my_df[:A])` works correctly (and if I get it correctly where we are heading with the language design `log(my_df[:A])` should be depreciated soon).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński The printout is on `Version 0.7.0-DEV.360`. `log.()` makes better sense. This kind of instability makes less

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the suggestions given in the comments, there isn't currently any bespoke functionality for this. See this issue for a discussion: https://github.com/JuliaData/DataTables.jl/issues/36